# How can I use `DoOutputsTuple` as either the parameter or the return of a `PTransform` in Apache Beam

Tags: python, apache-beam, ptransform

I have some `DoFn`s that return multiple output `PCollection`s, where one represents the "good" data path and the other captures errors to redirect them. Something like the following:

```py
output, error = (
        pcol
        | "Fix Timestamps"
        >> ParDo(ConvertTimestamp(), timestamp_field)
        .with_outputs(self.fail_tag, main=self.success_tag)
```

But I want to simplify and standardize, putting several of the `ParDo`/`DoFns` into a single `PTransform` that can be called directly.  Something like the following:

```py
class ConvertToBQFriendlyTypes(PTransform):
    def __init__(
        self,
        timestamp_fields: tuple[str, ...],
        fail_tag: str = FAIL_TAG,
        success_tag: str = SUCCESS_TAG,
    ):
        super().__init__()
        self.fail_tag = fail_tag
        self.success_tag = success_tag
        self.timestamp_fields = timestamp_fields

    class _ConvertSingleTimestamp(DoFn):
        def __init__(self, fail_tag: str = FAIL_TAG):
            super().__init__()
            self.fail_tag = fail_tag

        def process(
            self,
            element: dict,
            field_name: str,
        ) -> Iterable[dict[str, Any]] | Iterable[pvalue.TaggedOutput]:
            timestamp_raw = element[field_name]
            if hasattr(timestamp_raw, "to_utc_datetime"):
                timestamp_utc = timestamp_raw.to_utc_datetime(has_tz=True)  # type: ignore
            else:
                timestamp_utc = timestamp_raw
            if hasattr(timestamp_utc, "timestamp"):
                timestamp_utc = datetime.fromtimestamp(round(timestamp_utc.timestamp()))
            if hasattr(timestamp_utc, "strftime"):
                result = timestamp_utc.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")  # type: ignore
            elif isinstance(timestamp_utc, str) or timestamp_utc is None:
                result = timestamp_utc
            else:
                result = Failure( # `Failure` is a simple data class with these attributes:
                    pipeline_step="ConvertToBQFriendlyTypes",
                    element=element,
                    exception=TimestampError(
                        f'Field "{field_name}" has no means to convert time to a '
                        "string, which is needed for writing to BigQuery."
                    ),
                )
            if isinstance(result, Failure):
                yield pvalue.TaggedOutput(self.fail_tag, result)
            else:
                element[field_name] = result
                yield element

    def expand(
        self, pcoll: PCollection[dict[str, Any]] | pvalue.PValue
    ) -> PCollection[dict[str, Any]] | pvalue.PValue:
        for timestamp_field in self.timestamp_fields:
            pcoll = pcoll | f'Convert "{timestamp_field}"' >> ParDo(
                self._ConvertSingleTimestamp(self.fail_tag), timestamp_field
            ).with_outputs(self.fail_tag, main=self.success_tag)
        return pcoll
```

But this fails because a `PTransform`s `expand` method can only accept a `PCollection`, not a [`DoOutputsTuple` object](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.30.0/_modules/apache_beam/pvalue.html#DoOutputsTuple), like what is received from any `ParDo` that returns multiple outputs using [`with_outputs`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.30.0/_modules/apache_beam/transforms/core.html#ParDo). Moreover, it seems that a `PTransform` is only allowed to return a `PCollection`, not a `DoOutputsTuple`.

I have tried a few different ways to manage this, either splitting the outputs and managing each separately (in which case, I get either `TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable PCollection object` or `TypeError: 'PCollection' object is not subscriptable`, depending upon how I try to unpack it) or by working directly with the unpacked `DoOutputsTuple` (in which case, I get the dreaded `TypeError: '_InvalidUnpickledPCollection' object is not subscriptable...` error).

---

#### Does anyone know how I can create a `PTransform` that both receives a `DoOutputsTuple` as the first argument to its `expand` and returns a `DoOutputsTuple`?  If not, does anyone have any better suggestions for how to manage this?

I am tempted to use the [`pasgarde` package](https://github.com/tosun-si/pasgarde/tree/main) as it seems elegant, but (a) I don't want to create a dependency upon a lightly adopted open source package, and (b) it boxes me too tightly into only using Map, Flatmap, and Filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is something I also struggled recently. For solving this problem, I have looked at build-in `PTransforms` and tried to write something similar.

For example, `CoGroupByKey` (see [docs](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/python/aggregation/cogroupbykey/)) expects two individual `PCollections` as input. While `WriteToBigQuery` (see [here](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/current/apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.html#apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteToBigQuery)) returns multiple results.

`CoGroupByKey` utilizes Python dictionaries, while `WriteToBigQuery` uses a [custom class](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/current/apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.html#apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteResult) to return the output. The latter was (for my use case) a bit overkill, so I used a dictionary for the output as well.

As a MWE consider

```
import apache_beam as beam

class DoFnWithOutputs(beam.DoFn):
  def process(self, element):
    if element == 1:
      yield "one"
    else:
      yield beam.pvalue.TaggedOutput("not_one", False)


class SecondDoFn(beam.DoFn):
  def process(self, element):
    yield element + 5

      
class MyPtransform(beam.PTransform):
  def expand(self, pcoll):

    my_tagged_output = (
      pcoll['first_input']
      | beam.ParDo(DoFnWithOutputs()).with_outputs("not_one", main="one")
    )

    my_other_output = (
      pcoll['second_input']
      | beam.ParDo(SecondDoFn())
    )
    # we need to define an output dict
    # it might be possible to just use one k/v pair for the tagged output (not tested)  
    return {
      'not_one': my_tagged_output['not_one'],
      'one': my_tagged_output['one'],
      'other': my_other_output
    }      
        

with beam.Pipeline() as pipeline:
  first_input = pipeline | 'Create first input' >> beam.Create([1, 2, 3, 1])

  second_input = pipeline | 'Create second input' >> beam.Create([1, 2, 3, 4])

  ptransform_output = (
    {'first_input': first_input, 'second_input': second_input}  # Create the input dict
    | MyPtransform()
  )        
  
  (
    ptransform_output['one']
    | "map 1" >> beam.Map(lambda x: f"one: {x}")    
    | "print 1" >> beam.Map(print)
  )

  (
    ptransform_output['not_one']
    | "map != 1" >> beam.Map(lambda x: f"not_one: {x}") 
    | "print != 1" >> beam.Map(print)
  )

  (
    ptransform_output['other']
    | "map other" >> beam.Map(lambda x: f"other: {x}") 
    | "print other" >> beam.Map(print)
  )
```

which can be executed [here](https://play.beam.apache.org/?sdk=python&shared=XyuCvOYhwYG).

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.  It seems to break the rule that `PTransform`s return `PCollection`s, but as you say, it works.